# How to get file extension from string in C++

Tags: c++, string, filenames, file-extension

Given a string `"filename.conf"`, how to I verify the extension part?

I need a cross platform solution.

Comment: This question was from 2008, but if you came here today, see [std::filesystem::path](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/filesystem/path) which is standard (since c++17) and cross-platform. As mentioned below by [Roi Danton](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51949/how-to-get-file-extension-from-string-in-c/50881646#50881646) and [yves](https://stackoverflow.com/users/51386/yves).

Answer (score 35, accepted):

You have to make sure you take care of file names with more then one dot. 
example: `c:\.directoryname\file.name.with.too.many.dots.ext` would not be handled correctly by `strchr` or `find.`

My favorite would be the [boost filesystem library](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/release/libs/filesystem/index.html) that have an extension(path) function

Comment: Your directory name is easily handled by reverse find though :).

Comment: In my personal opinion boost solutions should not be listed as answers to c++ problems. Requiring a external library for something so simple seems a bit silly.

Comment: @marsh: yet, the _so simple_ problem has its special cases, especially when dealing with file systems - a concept which almost every major (and not so major) operating system has its own interpretation for. Consider, e.g., linux hidden files (`/home/oren/.conf'), or the case [mentioned by @Torlack](http://stackoverflow.com/a/51993/157274). @17 of 26, trying to mention your username alone should highlight the problems which may arise from over-simplifying how people use free-form naming ;)

Comment: @OrenS Nonetheless, boost solution should not be ever accepted as the answer to a question that doesn't ask how to do it with boost. It's misleading.

Comment: @MuhamedCicak ... well, portable solution for othervise involves some long piece of code which takes in account encoding of file names or/and use  other libraries (i suspect boost doesn't implement it from scratch, instead uses other packages or API where possible). Note, that even getting canonical path from partial one as a task is a huge problem with half-dozen of edge cases...

Comment: @Swift-FridayPie Yes, this one's a Gordian knot, I suppose I was just expressing my frustration towards almost any C++ question being answered using Boost, even some trivial problems that absolutely don't require any libraries to be solved.

Answer (score 181):

Is this too simple of a solution?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

int main()
{
  std::string fn = "filename.conf";
  if(fn.substr(fn.find_last_of(".") + 1) == "conf") {
    std::cout << "Yes..." << std::endl;
  } else {
    std::cout << "No..." << std::endl;
  }
}
```

Comment: @What happens when file name doesn't have extension and previous folder has . in its name?

Comment: I'm answering the question; which specifies "filename.conf", not your hypothetical.

Comment: By that logic, you could just say `return "Yes...";` with no check at all - it's implied that the solution should work for other inputs. As another counter example, a file named simply "conf" with no extension would also return "Yes..." given the above.

Comment: Warning to others: This is too simple of a solution to be used in production code except for narrow and specific projects that do not need to handle a variety of real-world end user scenarios.  File name parsing and handling is non-trivial.  I personally almost always use `boost::filesystem`, which is trivial to use, but provides the necessary support.  See http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_55_0/libs/filesystem/doc/index.htm

Comment: [std::filesystem::path::extension](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/filesystem/path/extension) is now part of the standard, check for eg [Roi Danton](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51949/how-to-get-file-extension-from-string-in-c/50881646#50881646) answer below.

Answer (score 44):

With C++17 and its [`std::filesystem::path::extension`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/filesystem/path/extension) (the library is the successor to boost::filesystem) you would make your statement more expressive than using e.g. `std::string`.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <filesystem> // C++17
namespace fs = std::filesystem;

int main()
{
    fs::path filePath = "my/path/to/myFile.conf";
    if (filePath.extension() == ".conf") // Heed the dot.
    {
        std::cout << filePath.stem() << " is a valid type.";
        // Output: "myFile is a valid type."
    }
    else
    {
        std::cout << filePath.filename() << " is an invalid type.";
        // Output: "myFile.cfg is an invalid type"
    }
}
```

See also [std::filesystem::path::stem](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/filesystem/path/stem), [std::filesystem::path::filename](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/filesystem/path/filename).

Answer (score 43):

The best way is to not write any code that does it but call existing methods.  In windows, the [PathFindExtension](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb773587(VS.85).aspx) method is probably the simplest.

So why would you not write your own?

Well, take the strrchr example, what happens when you use that method on the following string "c:\program files\AppleGate.Net\readme"?  Is ".Net\readme" the extension?  It is easy to write something that works for a few example cases, but can be much harder to write something that works for all cases.

Comment: +1 Writing no new code is often the best answer! The C# version of this was what I was after just now, but your answer got me there. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.path.getextension.aspx

Comment: This function (under Windows 7) will not properly handle "file.i i". Yes, this is valid, notice the space.

Comment: He has asked about retrieving the extension from a file, not a full path. In addition, a Windows API function would not be a good answer. This is absolutely not an answer, but a comment.

Comment: -1 for providing a platform-specific solution when a portable solution was requested by the OP.

Comment: +1 From me.  This question is the first one that comes up when you google 'mfc get file extension', and yours is the simplest answer that works.

Comment: I'm guessing you could just wrap the `strchr` that finds the dot inside a `strchr` call that finds the slash first. That way, folders with dots in the name don't get in the way.

Comment: Good points, but who said this was on Windows only?  OP specifically mentioned cross-platform.  And for the case mentioned of a full path, dot in pathname not in filename, filename with no extension, simply also look for path separators.  If dot is found before last path separator, then filename has no extension.  Check that the path with dot given by itself is a file, not a dir/folder, etc.  If one only needs this one function, no sense tying into a massive library, or platform specifics.  For each platform supported, make test cases for each "tricky" condition and handle it.  Roll your own.

Answer (score 33):

Assuming you have access to STL:

```
std::string filename("filename.conf");
std::string::size_type idx;

idx = filename.rfind('.');

if(idx != std::string::npos)
{
    std::string extension = filename.substr(idx+1);
}
else
{
    // No extension found
}
```

**Edit:** This is a cross platform solution since you didn't mention the platform.  If you're specifically on Windows, you'll want to leverage the Windows specific functions mentioned by others in the thread.

Comment: +1, this is the simplest solution in case you have a **file** in a string and not a path!

Answer (score 27):

Someone else mentioned boost but I just wanted to add the actual code to do this:

```
#include <boost/filesystem.hpp>
using std::string;
string texture         = foo->GetTextureFilename();
string file_extension  = boost::filesystem::extension(texture);
cout << "attempting load texture named " << texture
     << "    whose extensions seems to be " 
     << file_extension << endl;
// Use JPEG or PNG loader function, or report invalid extension
```

Comment: +1, thanks for posting an actual code snippet using boost. Don't forget to link with `-lboost_filesystem` and you get a working solution.

Answer (score 20):

actually the STL can do this without much code, I advise you learn a bit about the STL because it lets you do some fancy things, anyways this is what I use.

```
std::string GetFileExtension(const std::string& FileName)
{
    if(FileName.find_last_of(".") != std::string::npos)
        return FileName.substr(FileName.find_last_of(".")+1);
    return "";
}
```

this solution will always return the extension even on strings like "this.a.b.c.d.e.s.mp3" if it cannot find the extension it will return "".

Comment: breaks with "path/folder.with.dots/filename"

Answer (score 8):

Actually, the easiest way is

```
char* ext;
ext = strrchr(filename,'.')
```

One thing to remember: if `'.'` doesn't exist in filename, ext will be `NULL`.

Comment: This would not be perfect solution for UNIX hidden files that start with dot

Comment: should it be const char* ext?

Answer (score 6):

I've stumbled onto this question today myself, even though I already had a working code I figured out that it wouldn't work in some cases.

While some people already suggested using some external libraries, I prefer to write my own code for learning purposes.

Some answers included the method I was using in the first place (looking for the last "."), but I remembered that on linux hidden files/folders start with ".".
So if file file is hidden and has no extension, the whole file name would be taken for extension.
To avoid that I wrote this piece of code:

```
bool getFileExtension(const char * dir_separator, const std::string & file, std::string & ext)
{
    std::size_t ext_pos = file.rfind(".");
    std::size_t dir_pos = file.rfind(dir_separator);

    if(ext_pos>dir_pos+1)
    {
        ext.append(file.begin()+ext_pos,file.end());
        return true;
    }

    return false;
}
```

I haven't tested this fully, but I think that it should work.

Answer (score 4):

I'd go with [`boost::filesystem::extension`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_58_0/libs/filesystem/doc/reference.html#path-extension) ([`std::filesystem::path::extension`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/filesystem/path/extension) with C++17) but if you cannot use Boost and you just have to verify the extension, a simple solution is:

```
bool ends_with(const std::string &filename, const std::string &ext)
{
  return ext.length() <= filename.length() &&
         std::equal(ext.rbegin(), ext.rend(), filename.rbegin());
}

if (ends_with(filename, ".conf"))
{ /* ... */ }
```

Answer (score 3):

Using std::string's find/rfind solves THIS problem, but if you work a lot with paths then you should look at boost::filesystem::path since it will make your code much cleaner than fiddling with raw string indexes/iterators.

I suggest boost since it's a high quality, well tested, (open source and commercially) free and fully portable library.

Answer (score 3):

You can use **strrchr()** to find last occurence of .(dot) and get .(dot) based extensions files.
Check the below code for example.

```
#include<stdio.h>

void GetFileExtension(const char* file_name) {

    int ext = '.';
    const char* extension = NULL;
    extension = strrchr(file_name, ext);

    if(extension == NULL){
        printf("Invalid extension encountered\n");
        return;
    }

    printf("File extension is %s\n", extension);
}

int main()
{
    const char* file_name = "c:\\.directoryname\\file.name.with.too.many.dots.ext";
    GetFileExtension(file_name);
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
_splitpath, _wsplitpath, _splitpath_s, _wsplitpath_w
```

This is Windows (Platform SDK) only

Answer (score 2):

For char array-type strings you can use this:

```
#include <ctype.h>
#include <string.h>

int main()
{
    char filename[] = "apples.bmp";
    char extension[] = ".jpeg";

    if(compare_extension(filename, extension) == true)
    {
        // .....
    } else {
        // .....
    }

    return 0;
}

bool compare_extension(char *filename, char *extension)
{
    /* Sanity checks */

    if(filename == NULL || extension == NULL)
        return false;

    if(strlen(filename) == 0 || strlen(extension) == 0)
        return false;

    if(strchr(filename, '.') == NULL || strchr(extension, '.') == NULL)
        return false;

    /* Iterate backwards through respective strings and compare each char one at a time */

    for(int i = 0; i < strlen(filename); i++)
    {
        if(tolower(filename[strlen(filename) - i - 1]) == tolower(extension[strlen(extension) - i - 1]))
        {
            if(i == strlen(extension) - 1)
                return true;
        } else
            break;
    }

    return false;
}
```

Can handle file paths in addition to filenames. Works with both C and C++. And cross-platform.

Comment: You could decrease number of conditions. Use `strlen(extension)` in `for` condition. Then if chars does not match return false. Outside `for` loop return true.

Answer (score 2):

A NET/CLI version using System::String

```
   System::String^ GetFileExtension(System::String^ FileName)
   {
       int Ext=FileName->LastIndexOf('.');
       if( Ext != -1 )
           return FileName->Substring(Ext+1);
       return "";
   }
```

Comment: This is not Visual C++, it is [.NET/CLI](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/68td296t.aspx).

Comment: @Victor I edited the answer. Thanks for clarification.

Answer (score 2):

If you use Qt library, you can give a try to [QFileInfo](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qfileinfo.html)'s [suffix()](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qfileinfo.html#suffix)

Comment: What does Qt have to do with this question?  Why introduce a large third-party dependency for a simple string manipulation?  If going that route, why not just use boost?

Comment: @derpface It's *if you use it*. Since it's common, *if* you're using it, `suffix()` is in there and works fine. If you aren't using it, it'd obviously be silly to move your entire project over to Qt just for getting file extensions.

Answer (score 2):

Good answers but I see most of them has some problems:
First of all I think a good answer should work for complete file names which have their path headings, also it should work for linux or windows or as mentioned it should be cross platform. For most of answers; file names with no extension but a path with a folder name including dot, the function will fail to return the correct extension: examples of some test cases could be as follow:

```
    const char filename1 = {"C:\\init.d\\doc"}; // => No extention
    const char filename2 = {"..\\doc"}; //relative path name => No extention
    const char filename3 = {""}; //emputy file name => No extention
    const char filename4 = {"testing"}; //only single name => No extention
    const char filename5 = {"tested/k.doc"}; // normal file name => doc
    const char filename6 = {".."}; // parent folder => No extention
    const char filename7 = {"/"}; // linux root => No extention
    const char filename8 = {"/bin/test.d.config/lx.wize.str"}; // ordinary path! => str
```

"*brian newman*" suggestion will fail for filename1 and filename4.
and most of other answers which are based on reverse find will fail for filename1.
I suggest including the following method in your source:
which is function returning index of first character of extension or the length of given string if not found.

```
size_t find_ext_idx(const char* fileName)
{
    size_t len = strlen(fileName);
    size_t idx = len-1;
    for(size_t i = 0; *(fileName+i); i++) {
        if (*(fileName+i) == '.') {
            idx = i;
        } else if (*(fileName + i) == '/' || *(fileName + i) == '\\') {
            idx = len - 1;
        }
    }
    return idx+1;
}
```

you could use the above code in your c++ application like below:

```
std::string get_file_ext(const char* fileName)
{
    return std::string(fileName).substr(find_ext_idx(fileName));
}
```

The last point in some cases the a folder is given to file name as argument and includes a dot in the folder name the function will return folder's dot trailing so better first to user check that the given name is a filename and not folder name.

Answer (score 2):

This is a solution I came up with.  Then, I noticed that it is similar to what @serengeor posted.

It works with `std::string` and `find_last_of`, but the basic idea will also work if modified to use `char` arrays and `strrchr`.
It handles hidden files, and extra dots representing the current directory.  It is platform independent.

```
string PathGetExtension( string const & path )
{
  string ext;

  // Find the last dot, if any.
  size_t dotIdx = path.find_last_of( "." );
  if ( dotIdx != string::npos )
  {
    // Find the last directory separator, if any.
    size_t dirSepIdx = path.find_last_of( "/\\" );

    // If the dot is at the beginning of the file name, do not treat it as a file extension.
    // e.g., a hidden file:  ".alpha".
    // This test also incidentally avoids a dot that is really a current directory indicator.
    // e.g.:  "alpha/./bravo"
    if ( dotIdx > dirSepIdx + 1 )
    {
      ext = path.substr( dotIdx );
    }
  }

  return ext;
}
```

Unit test:

```
int TestPathGetExtension( void )
{
  int errCount = 0;

  string tests[][2] = 
  {
    { "/alpha/bravo.txt", ".txt" },
    { "/alpha/.bravo", "" },
    { ".alpha", "" },
    { "./alpha.txt", ".txt" },
    { "alpha/./bravo", "" },
    { "alpha/./bravo.txt", ".txt" },
    { "./alpha", "" },
    { "c:\\alpha\\bravo.net\\charlie.txt", ".txt" },
  };

  int n = sizeof( tests ) / sizeof( tests[0] );

  for ( int i = 0; i < n; ++i )
  {
    string ext = PathGetExtension( tests[i][0] );
    if ( ext != tests[i][1] )
    {
      ++errCount;
    }
  }

  return errCount;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

So, [using `std::filesystem` is the best answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50881646/616460), but if for whatever reason you don't have C++17 features available, this will work even if the input string includes directories:

```
string getextn (const string &fn) {
  int sep = fn.find_last_of(".\\/");
  return (sep >= 0 && fn[sep] == '.') ? fn.substr(sep) : "";
}
```

I'm adding this because the rest of the answers here are either strangely complicated or fail if the path to the file contains a dot and the file doesn't. I think the fact that `find_last_of` can look for multiple characters is often overlooked.

It works with both `/` and `\` path separators. It fails if the extension itself contains a slash but that's usually too rare to matter. It doesn't do any filtering for filenames that start with a dot and contain no other dots -- if this matters to you then [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13430107/616460) is the least unreasonable answer here.

[Example input / output](https://ideone.com/uwgMkE):

```
/ => ''
./ => ''
./pathname/ => ''
./path.name/ => ''
pathname/ => ''
path.name/ => ''
c:\path.name\ => ''
/. => '.'
./. => '.'
./pathname/. => '.'
./path.name/. => '.'
pathname/. => '.'
path.name/. => '.'
c:\path.name\. => '.'
/.git_ignore => '.git_ignore'
./.git_ignore => '.git_ignore'
./pathname/.git_ignore => '.git_ignore'
./path.name/.git_ignore => '.git_ignore'
pathname/.git_ignore => '.git_ignore'
path.name/.git_ignore => '.git_ignore'
c:\path.name\.git_ignore => '.git_ignore'
/filename => ''
./filename => ''
./pathname/filename => ''
./path.name/filename => ''
pathname/filename => ''
path.name/filename => ''
c:\path.name\filename => ''
/filename. => '.'
./filename. => '.'
./pathname/filename. => '.'
./path.name/filename. => '.'
pathname/filename. => '.'
path.name/filename. => '.'
c:\path.name\filename. => '.'
/filename.tar => '.tar'
./filename.tar => '.tar'
./pathname/filename.tar => '.tar'
./path.name/filename.tar => '.tar'
pathname/filename.tar => '.tar'
path.name/filename.tar => '.tar'
c:\path.name\filename.tar => '.tar'
/filename.tar.gz => '.gz'
./filename.tar.gz => '.gz'
./pathname/filename.tar.gz => '.gz'
./path.name/filename.tar.gz => '.gz'
pathname/filename.tar.gz => '.gz'
path.name/filename.tar.gz => '.gz'
c:\path.name\filename.tar.gz => '.gz'
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's a function that takes a path/filename as a string and returns the extension as a string.  It is all standard c++, and should work cross-platform for most platforms.

Unlike several other answers here, it handles the odd cases that windows' PathFindExtension handles, based on PathFindExtensions's documentation.

```
wstring get_file_extension( wstring filename )
{
    size_t last_dot_offset = filename.rfind(L'.');
    // This assumes your directory separators are either \ or /
    size_t last_dirsep_offset = max( filename.rfind(L'\\'), filename.rfind(L'/') );

    // no dot = no extension
    if( last_dot_offset == wstring::npos )
        return L"";

    // directory separator after last dot = extension of directory, not file.
    // for example, given C:\temp.old\file_that_has_no_extension we should return "" not "old"
    if( (last_dirsep_offset != wstring::npos) && (last_dirsep_offset > last_dot_offset) )
        return L"";

    return filename.substr( last_dot_offset + 1 );
}
```

Comment: Hi, there is a problem with your solution:
`max( filename.rfind(L'\\'), filename.rfind(L'/') )`
will compare two unsigned values, one of them could be `npos` which is the biggest possible unsigned integer. So it might look like there is no folder even when it is there!

Answer (score 1):

I use these two functions to get the *extension* and *filename without extension*:

```
std::string fileExtension(std::string file){

    std::size_t found = file.find_last_of(".");
    return file.substr(found+1);

}

std::string fileNameWithoutExtension(std::string file){

    std::size_t found = file.find_last_of(".");
    return file.substr(0,found);    
}
```

And these `regex` approaches for certain extra requirements:

```
std::string fileExtension(std::string file){

    std::regex re(".*[^\\.]+\\.([^\\.]+$)");
    std::smatch result;
    if(std::regex_match(file,result,re))return result[1];
    else return "";

}

std::string fileNameWithoutExtension(std::string file){

    std::regex re("(.*[^\\.]+)\\.[^\\.]+$");
    std::smatch result;
    if(std::regex_match(file,result,re))return result[1];
    else return file;

}
```

Extra requirements that are met by the regex method:

1. If *filename* is like `.config` or something like this, *extension* will be an empty string and *filename without extension* will be `.config`.
2. If filename doesn't have any extension, extention will be an empty string, *filename without extension* will be the *filename* unchanged.

---

**EDIT:**

The extra requirements can also be met by the following:

```
std::string fileExtension(const std::string& file){
    std::string::size_type pos=file.find_last_of('.');
    if(pos!=std::string::npos&&pos!=0)return file.substr(pos+1);
    else return "";
}


std::string fileNameWithoutExtension(const std::string& file){
    std::string::size_type pos=file.find_last_of('.');
    if(pos!=std::string::npos&&pos!=0)return file.substr(0,pos);
    else return file;
}
```

**Note:**

Pass only the filenames (not path) in the above functions.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use [strstr](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/cstring/strstr/)

```
char* lastSlash;
lastSlash = strstr(filename, ".");
```

Answer (score 0):

Or you can use this:

```
    char *ExtractFileExt(char *FileName)
    {
        std::string s = FileName;
        int Len = s.length();
        while(TRUE)
        {
            if(FileName[Len] != '.')
                Len--;
            else
            {
                char *Ext = new char[s.length()-Len+1];
                for(int a=0; a<s.length()-Len; a++)
                    Ext[a] = FileName[s.length()-(s.length()-Len)+a];
                Ext[s.length()-Len] = '\0';
                return Ext;
            }
        }
    }
```

This code is cross-platform

Answer (score -1):

If you happen to use [Poco](http://pocoproject.org/) libraries you can do:

```
#include <Poco/Path.h>

...

std::string fileExt = Poco::Path("/home/user/myFile.abc").getExtension(); // == "abc"
```

Answer (score -1):

If you consider the extension as the last dot and the possible characters after it, but only if they don't contain the directory separator character, the following function returns the extension starting index, or -1 if no extension found. When you have that you can do what ever you want, like strip the extension, change it, check it etc.

```
long get_extension_index(string path, char dir_separator = '/') {
    // Look from the end for the first '.',
    // but give up if finding a dir separator char first
    for(long i = path.length() - 1; i >= 0; --i) {
        if(path[i] == '.') {
            return i;
        }
        if(path[i] == dir_separator) {
            return -1;
        }
    }
    return -1;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

I used PathFindExtension() function to know whether it is a valid tif file or not.

```
#include <Shlwapi.h>
bool A2iAWrapperUtility::isValidImageFile(string imageFile)
{
    char * pStrExtension = ::PathFindExtension(imageFile.c_str());

    if (pStrExtension != NULL && strcmp(pStrExtension, ".tif") == 0)
    {
        return true;
    }

    return false;
}
```