# How to get Filename without extension in Unreal?

Tags: c++, unreal-engine4

I've been using the below code to get the filename and it's works fine for me. But I the file name WITHOUT extension(.uasset).

```
const FString fileName = FPaths::GetCleanFilename(filePath);
```

Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: possible duplicate of [easy-way-to-remove-extension-from-a-filename](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6417817/easy-way-to-remove-extension-from-a-filename)

Comment: I would not close it as a duplicate since it has an Unreal Engine specific solution. See the answer.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to get file extension from string in C++](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/51949/how-to-get-file-extension-from-string-in-c)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use FPaths::Split to do that:

```
FPaths::Split(fileName,path,fileNameWithoutExtension,extension);
```

Comment: thanks and also I found working with  FPaths::GetBaseFilename(filePath);