# Naming a new file from the command line

Tags: c++

How do I create a new file based on the command line.

For example if my argv[1] is file.extension I want to create a new text file named file.txt.

I tried this:

```
ofstream a;
a.open("argv[1].txt");
```

But it very obviously creates a file called argv[1].txt instead of file.txt

Comment: Please delete this question

Comment: It is a legitimate question

Comment: its an exercise in how to dissect a problem into underlying steps - close this and think about solutions to smaller decisions which together solve this question

Comment: @ScottStensland: It's hard to find smaller decisions here....;-)

Answer (score 1):

```
a.open( (std::string(argv[1]) + ".txt").c_str() ); // if parameter is file with no extension
```

or

```
a.open( argv[1] ); // if parameter is file with extension
```

Possibly:

```
std::string file = argv[1];
// do whatever you want (change extension, as commented)
a.open( file.c_str() );
```

But I agree this question should probably be deleted....don't think it will help anyone else....

Comment: The file already has an extension, I want to remove that extension and replace it with .txt

Comment: Then, just use google with "c++ change file extension" and you'll magically find http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6417817/easy-way-to-remove-extension-from-a-filename

Comment: I get this error : no matching function for call to ‘std::basic_fstream<char, std::char_traits<char> >::open(std::string&)’

Comment: Edited the post, it takes a `const char*`: use `.c_str()` to get it from the `std::string`

Comment: Thanks for the help, although it doesn't create a new file at all for some reason. And how do I change the extension to .txt from .extension

Comment: So do you actually just want `rename`? http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/c/rename

Comment: What if  I want to prepend something to the filename? currently I get a.txt as the output. I want to get my_a.txt as the output now. I tried it using a + but got an error: invalid operands of types ‘const char [3]’ and ‘const char*’ to binary ‘operator+

Comment: This just opens the file, ext step is to write into it....please pickup a tutorial and follow it....